# Windows Vista doesn't recognise CD Drive after iTunes install

Tags: windows-vista, itunes, installation, optical-drive

After installing iTunes I can no longer load cd's as it appears that my CD Drive doesn't exist

I've found postings on other sites to repair this by deleting the upper and lower limit keys in the system registry for the device.

However after updating the registry iTunes then doesn't recognize the drive, giving an error on startup and suggesting a re-install. Re-installing just breaks things again.

Does anyone have a solution that allows both iTunes and other apps to access the CD-Drive?

Comment: So, did you try deleting the upper and lower limits?

Comment: Yes, thats what causes iTunes to not recognise the drive.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://support-web.acer-euro.com/app/csd/etkdb.nsf/4b7a708d8dbc41cdc1256bd6003c0165/e5e8163f0d01bf60c12572ec00266cce?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,dvd) worked for me when my drive disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me, too.  Note that the official Microsoft link for this is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929461  After performing this step, I had to uninstall and reinstall AnyDVD.

Comment: But when I do this iTunes gives me the error on start up prompting me to re-install. Thus I'm in an endless loop of having either iTunes working or all other apps.